# What does コピー mean in this context?

Tags: translation, music

> A: 他にもラルクコピーしてましたか？
>
> B: じゃあ最後にもう一度聴いてくれ…虹。ってやってた

I know that ラルク is the band L'arc En Ciel. What does **コピー** mean here? What does the first sentence say?

Comment: Although this forum certainly allows for these questions, it often seems like you are trying to learn Japanese just by translating tweets.  I would not recommend that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`コピー` 'copy' in this context means to play a song of a band in the format as close as possible to the original. Often, you reconstruct the music score by listening to that song. If it is done in this way, it is particularly called `耳コピー` 'copying by ear'.

`じゃあ最後にもう一度聴いてくれ ... 虹。` means 'Then, please listen again. This will be the last song Niji.'

Comment: So then when ってやってた is added, what does that sentence say?

Comment: @language_hacker 'They said doing as ...' or 'They said that ...'

Comment: じゃあ最後にもう一度聴いてくれ…虹。ってやってた still doesn't make sense to me as an answer to what the other person said. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: @language A is likely reporting about a concert to B. A is saying "They were going like 'Then, please listen again. (The next song is) Niji' ".

Answer (score -3):

A conversation wouldn't flow that way, at all.  I'm positive.  Is there more context?  ってやってた is very poor Japanese.  It's something that would not be said on a tape or on in an instructional book.  This is what A-san would say: 何からその情報を得たのか.  It's because って doesn't belong and やってた would mean that you're speaking down to the listener, as if the listener is a mangy dog or a very very low subordinate who warrants no respect at all.  Nobody is so rude, except for a rowdy high school student, especially not in writing.  Even in the case of high school students, they are usually insincere with this kind of jarring.

Copy isn't used properly here.  So, it doesn't have any meaning.  Copy has no meaning in this sentence.  While it's true that 耳コピー has a meaning: 'copy by ear', it is very rarely used, even when asking for such a thing.  Also, I am here with a friend of mine, and neither of us can think of any other case where a word directly proceeds コピー.  There's always a particle between two words where the second word is コピー, with only the exception of the word 耳コピー.

Here's the question Native Japanese speakers will ask themselves when they read this sentence:

> どういう状況でコピーを使ったのか？-> What is it a copy of?

It seems the only (extremely unlikely) possibility is that the speaker is saying: "Is it a L'arc En Ciel copy band?"  There's an even less likely possibility that they're saying: "Is it a copy of L'arc En Ciel's song?"  If that were the case, the speaker would definitely say ラリクのコピーバンドですか or ラリクの歌をコピーしましたか.  In either case, 他にも would cease to have any place in the sentence.  他にも would sound equally as strange and out of place in one of these corrected versions as ラリクコピー sounds in the original sentence.

So, isn't it possible that you misheard what was said?  That seems most likely.

Comment: It seems you missed the action. The original text is an ugly tweet, but it has been reformatted as above.  See the edit that @You has done to see the full original text (which is then not "misheard").  Yet, it is also possible that the writer of the tweet is bad at his own mother tongue…

Comment: 1. Although the original format in the question was ugly, the conversation is completely normal Japanese. 2. `耳コピー` is a common word among musicians. 3. There are words like `カラーコピー`, `レーザーコピー`, `白黒コピー`. 4. Existence of such compound nouns is totally irrlevant to the question. 5. Your Japanese sentence `どういう...` does not match with the English translation `What is it ...` 6. It is not clear how that sentence will be related to the context. 7 They are saying whether other songs were copied. It is not 'even less likely'. 8. They are not asking whether it is a copy band. 9. Not `ラリク` but `ラルク`.

Comment: I think I now understand why you were discussing compounds including `コピー`. You parsed the sentence wrong. You probably took `ラルクコピーして` as `ラルクコピー + して`. That is wrong. It is `ラルクを + コピーして` with the `を` omitted. Omitting `を` is completely natural Japanese.

Comment: The やる in this sentence doesn't mean give, nor is the patronizing ～てやる form. ～ってやってた here is colloquial for とやっていた, and the やる means do.